# error in computing fft in tensorflow for float variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, fft

I have declared my x as float variables and while computing the fft of the variables gives an error. my input is not a complex number, it will be positive and negative float values. so what should I be declaring the variable as ?
my code

```
x=tf.Variable([1.0,2.3,3.99,4,5.1],dtype=tf.int32)
model = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess= tf.Session()
sess.run(model)
print(sess.run(tf.fft(x))
```

error

```
TypeError: Input 'input' of 'FFT' Op has float32 that doesnot match expected type of complex64
```

Updated code from comment given

I have modified the variable

```
a = tf.Variable([1.3, -2, 3.6, 4.1, 5.9],dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=tf.float32)
c = tf.complex(a, b)
d = tf.fft(c)
model = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(model)
print(sess.run(d))
```

I get another error

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'FFT' with these attrs.  Registered kernels:<no registered kernels> [[Node: FFT = FFT[](Complex)]]
```

I can easily perform with scipy

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft as scifft
b = [1.3, -2, 3.6, 4.1, 5.9]
print(scifft(b))
```

and get the result as

```
[ 12.90000000+0.j   -3.72426458+7.8072391j   0.52426458+4.16797523j   0.52426458-4.16797523j   -3.72426458-7.8072391j  ]
```

how can get the same value using the tensorflow computation ?

Comment: What happens if you convert those floats to their equivalent complex values (i.e. `[complex(x, 0) for x in your_list]`) and pass that in?

Comment: @Tagc I have updated my code and new error .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

which version of tensorflow are you using ? U need to install the GPU version for computing the FFT.
I had similar problem, first i struggle hard to understand this. 
you can use tf.cast for changing the variable type 
example :`tf.cast(tf.Varaible(x,dtype=tf.int32),dtype=tf.complex64)`

Comment: FYI: TensorFlow now supports FFT on CPUs (since May 2017).